# Why is the button full screen?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager

The code:

```java
package src.com.Scanner.Scan;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        JFrame Frame = new JFrame();
        Frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        Frame.setVisible(true);
        JButton Button = new JButton("test");
        Button.setBounds(25,25,5,5);
        Button.setBorder(null);
        Button.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        Frame.add(Button);

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("Name", "JOHN");
        obj.put("unix", "50000");

        String objstring = obj.toString();

        String EncodedString = Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(objstring.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        System.out.println(obj);
        System.out.println(EncodedString);

        byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(EncodedString);
        String decodedString = new String(decodedBytes);

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject obJSONObject = new JSONObject();

        obJSONObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(decodedString);

        System.out.println(obJSONObject);

    }
}
```

But the button is fullscreen like full screen, not the size I set why does it do that and how can I fix it?

Im using IntelliJ and Java 16.

Comment: The code could have expressed this problem with core Java in <25 lines of code. The answer to your question is that the button is being placed in the default location of a border layout (the `CENTER`) and the behavior of the center constraint is to stretch whatever is in it to fill the entire width and height. Post a drawing or ASCII art of the intended layout.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson https://imgur.com/a/tZEFev9

Comment: 1) That image does not match the code shown (the button in the code would be square, whereas the drawing shows a rectangular button). 2) I meant a drawing of the **total GUI,** not just the bit you are trying to achieve in this code. I suspect there must be more components ultimately going in it. A full-screen window for a 'button in the upper left' seems overkill.

Comment: `JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout` by default